# R Code from java giving error : Error in lev(modelFit) : could not find function "lev"

Tags: java, r, spring-boot

Am getting RConnection in java, am assigning data by following

```
rConnection.assign(".tmp.","'{json goes  here}'");

rCon.parseAndEval("try(eval(parse(text=model_S(.tmp.))),silent=TRUE)");
```

when the above call is made  am getting

> Error in lev(modelFit) : could not find function "lev"

In R, I have installed Caret, Kernlab packages also. When I execute the same code in R, its working fine. but when the call is made from Java, its giving error.

Any inputs will be Helpful. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using following  statement :

```java
rCon.parseAndEval("library(caret)")
```

resolved the  issue.